# What is the equivalent of square brackets for multiple characters?

Tags: java, regex

Regex `[abcd]` can take any one character out of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

What if I want to take any one string out of `abc`, `def` and `ijk`.

So something like `["abcd" "def" "efg"]` (but this obviously doesn't work).

How would I do this in Java?

Comment: Is there any difference between your question and description ?

Comment: The answer is: `with a smile on your face`. Remember, people like working with smiling people. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Use a vertical bar between items `|`

Comment: google regex, first link is wikipedia, click on it, in the basic concept part it is stated : Boolean "or" A vertical bar separates alternatives. For example, gray|grey can match "gray" or "grey". Try looking a little bit for answers before posting a question.

Comment: It's customary to tell us what you've tried so far. However, it looks like PrR3 has already answered.

Answer (score 11):

your regex could look like this:

```
(abcd|def|efg)
```

Comment: Actually, `(?:abcd|def|efg)` would be the "exact" equivalent, because using `(...)` introduces the overhead of a capture, might include that capture in the result (depending on the method used), and will affect the numbering of other groups used in the pattern.

Answer (score 4):

`[]` is only for single characters.

You can use `|` for multiple characters (`X|Y` means ["Either X or Y"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)):

```
abcd|def|efg
```

**In case there's anything else in the regex**, you'd want to surround it with brackets:

```
other(abcd|def|efg)stuff
```

The above matches these strings:

```
otherabcdstuff
otherdefstuff
otherefgstuff
```

Where-as:

```
otherabcd|def|efgstuff
```

would obviously match these strings:

```
otherabcd
def
efgstuff
```